# Plausibility of plan to use DOM4J with JTables & Action Listeners

Tags: java, xml, swing, dom, dom4j

I am preparing to embark on a large solo project at my place of employment. First let me describe the project. I have been asked to create a Java program that can take a CamT54 file (which is just a xml file) and have java display the information in table form. Then users should be given the ability to remove certain components from the table and have it go back to xml format with the changes.

I'm not well versed in dealing with XML in Java so this is going to be a learn and work task. Before I begin investing time I would like to know that my approach is the best approach.

My plan is to use DOM4J to do the parsing and handling of the xml. I will use a JTable to display the data and incorporate some buttons to the GUI that allow the modifications of the data through the use of some action listeners.

Would this be a plausible plan? Can DOM4J effectively allow xml data to be displayed in a table format and furthermore could that data be easily modified or deleted then resaved to a new xml?

Comment: Also consider [jaxb](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jaxb/info).

Comment: if you are not restricted to use swing, you may give a try to javafx treetableview. treetableview may help you (and user) to view hierarchical structure of xml more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion guleryuz. I will look into that as I'm not restricted to use anything as long as it gets done.

Trashgod, 

I did consider JaxB as it was used in an earlier project the only issue is that I believe the program needs to give the user the ability to easily delete elements from the XML. My understanding with JaxB is done ahead of time so deleting elements during runtime isn't feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would go ahead and answer this as I finished the program and wanted to post what I thought was the easiest solution in case anyone else needed help.

It turned out the easiest approach (for me at least) was to use the standard DOM parser, here are the steps I took.

1. Parsed the entire XML into String array lists. XPath was required for this, I also had to convert the elements into Strings and remove the extra tag information from the string using substrings since I only wanted the actual value.
2. I populated a JTable with these arrays.
3. Once users finished editing and clicked a save button then another Dom parser would take the original XML and change each and every attribute using the values from the Arrays (that were deleted and repopulated with the JTable cell values when the user clicked "save").